# Joomla 1.0, administrator link redirect to "installation/index.php", how to prevent this redirection?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm just migrate my old Joomla 1.0 site to localhost, fronted works fine, but when I try to open administrator its redirect to  "installation/index.php" file and nothing to open,
how to prevent this thing, I'm  check path in below code which is present in in administrator/index2.php file its correct path but still administrator not open.

```
if (!file_exists( 'C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/configuration.php' )) {
       header( 'Location: ../installation/index.php' );
       exit();
       }
```

Comment: try to remove installation folder.Normally after installation we need to remove installation folder manually in older version new version do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Jobin responding to me.. installation directory already renamed in my site root

Comment: are you sure that you have `configuration.php` and not only `configuration.php-dist`?

Comment: And make sure configuration.php is readable by Joomla not just apache.

Comment: I get this often after a migration. It has always been a cache issue for me and simply clearing the browser cache fixes it.

Why not test the If statement above by taking it out temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the source file of administration/index2.php validates the file in path:

> 'C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/configuration.php'

Was it modified?