# Joomla administrator redirects to installation

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a Joomla 2.5 site were I can no longer access the administrator panel. That only redirects me to /installation/index.php which (as it should) gives a 404. I think this happened after an upgrade.

I tried to clear browser cache as suggested here: [Joomla 1.0, administrator link redirect to "installation/index.php", how to prevent this redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287307/joomla-1-0-administrator-link-redirect-to-installation-index-php-how-to-prev)

But that didn't work.

A long time ago, back in the 1.x days, there were some security advices on the Joomla site which among other things suggested to move configuration.php outside the public_html directory which I followed. I can't find them now, but I tried to copy the configuration.php file to Joomla root directory as well as keeping it at the directory which is defined in defines.php (`define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION'`).

Any ideas?

#### My extensions

```
bash-3.2$ find plugins/ -type d
plugins/
plugins/authentication
plugins/authentication/gmail
plugins/authentication/joomla
plugins/authentication/ldap
plugins/captcha
plugins/captcha/recaptcha
plugins/content
plugins/content/emailcloak
plugins/content/finder
plugins/content/geshi
plugins/content/geshi/geshi
plugins/content/geshi/geshi/geshi
plugins/content/joomla
plugins/content/loadmodule
plugins/content/pagebreak
plugins/content/pagenavigation
plugins/content/vote
plugins/editors-xtd
plugins/editors-xtd/article
plugins/editors-xtd/image
plugins/editors-xtd/pagebreak
plugins/editors-xtd/readmore
plugins/editors
plugins/editors/codemirror
plugins/editors/none
plugins/editors/tinymce
plugins/extension
plugins/extension/joomla
plugins/finder
plugins/finder/categories
plugins/finder/contacts
plugins/finder/content
plugins/finder/newsfeeds
plugins/finder/weblinks
plugins/quickicon
plugins/quickicon/extensionupdate
plugins/quickicon/joomlaupdate
plugins/search
plugins/search/categories
plugins/search/contacts
plugins/search/content
plugins/search/newsfeeds
plugins/search/weblinks
plugins/system
plugins/system/cache
plugins/system/debug
plugins/system/highlight
plugins/system/languagecode
plugins/system/languagecode/language
plugins/system/languagecode/language/en-GB
plugins/system/languagefilter
plugins/system/log
plugins/system/logout
plugins/system/p3p
plugins/system/redirect
plugins/system/remember
plugins/system/sef
plugins/user
plugins/user/contactcreator
plugins/user/joomla
plugins/user/profile
plugins/user/profile/fields
plugins/user/profile/profiles
```

Comment: Have you recently installed any extensions or edited any Joomla core files?

Comment: The embarrassing fact is that I don't pay much attention to this site. So I don't remember what I did back when it stopped working.

Comment: I also tried to just unzip a new version (2.5.x) over the old one (2.5.x). So the core files should be untouched.

Comment: do you have any site protection components or plugins, such as RSFirewall or anything else?

Comment: I don't remember installing anything like that, no.

Comment: You updated to the current version?
If you unzipped the complete download now you will have the installation folder and you need to delete it.
Was this a site that was migrated from 1.5?

Comment: This was a site that was migrated from 1.5, yes. I did delete the installation directory. I did upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if wont work move to another point.

**1.** Change this

```
if (file_exists(JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php')) {
   header('Location: '.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')).'installation/index.php');
```

To this:

```
if (file_exists(JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php')) {
header('Location: '.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],   'index.php')).JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php');
```

Its line 25-26 in `administrator/includes/framework.php`

**2.** Remove line 23-32 in this file - it checks for installation folder and size of configuration file, if you dont have installation folder and configuration file is ok, you can remove this

**3.** set variables `$sef` and `$sef_rewrite` to zero in configuration.php

Comment: It turned out that the problem was in "administrator/defines.php". But thanks to your solution I was able to catch the error in a log. I don't know why I didn't find this earlier :-/

Comment: What was the problem? I was just trying to give you the access to admin, i was sure, that plugins cant be the issue.

Comment: Long time ago there was a security advice on Joomla site, which now is removed, to move the configuration.php out of the public_html directory. I believed that all I did was to change the `JPATH_CONFIGURATION`-variable in `JPATH/defines.php`. But It turned out there was a file `JPATH/administrator/defines.php` which I also changed back then. When my provider migrated me to a new server the paths which I had previously (and stupidly) hardcoded changed. They (or me, don't remember) fixed the first defines.php, but I didn't realize that there were another one in the administrator dir.

Comment: I did a grep of all my php-files to find someone that contained the old path. That way I found the problem. TLDR; There's no fix for stupidity.

Answer (score 1):

**Diagnosing The Situation**

Perhaps you should start with diagnosing the plugins? By removing them all and adding in one by one to see what one causes an issue. As you recently updated, a plugin perhaps is causing this issue as it is outdated and is creating conflictions between the software and the extension.

The issue may be based around that the configuration cannot be found, so Joomla presumes you have not installed the software.

**Have you done all of these?**

- Removed installation folder
- Checked if .htaccess isn't causing the issue
- Attempt a downgrade and upgrade?

Comment: Do you mean it is possible to uninstall a plugin by removing it's directory or what are you suggesting? I don't think htaccess causing the problem, it should been the file that was within the zip-file as far as I can tell. I might do a diff to verify that.

Comment: Disable them in the extensions manager. But not the core ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think plugins would not cause redirecting to installation folder. Most likely the system thinks it's not installed yet, which would most likely be caused due to a missing configuration.php file in a location where Joomla expects it to be.

You can try to add something like this to the *end* of defines.php:

```
var_dump(file_exists(JPATH_CONFIGURATION.DS.'configuration.php'));
```

If it outputs true - that means config file exists and the problem is not in it.
Then I would rename .htaccess to htaccess.txt to make sure it has no effect.
If that doesn't work you could also lookup index.php file in public_html folder and make sure no changes have been made to it.

I'm pretty sure config file is not in its location and this should resolve your issue. Hit me back if it doesn't and I will help you further.

Comment: P.S. you extensions list only shows extension type folders which is not useful. Try to list extensions inside those folders.

Comment: Oh. Stupid me, I updated my question. I will try to get around to test your suggestion later today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this things

- Delete the joomla installation file directory: c:/host/project path/your site/installation
- Check your server and restart it
- Be ensure the required services are available on the server
- Try installing the new Joomla package http://www.joomla.org/download.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you need to delete the /installation folder after an installation. Otherwise if it finds this folder and you get redirected there.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons Joomla does not allow you to be redirected to your site front-end or back-end before you delete the installation folder after the installation is complete.Please make sure the joomla `/installation` folder is deleted, and if yes, restart your server if possible.